# Hyperlinked Image Disappears

Tags: html, css

I am trying to hyperlink an image, but when I do, it makes the image (#26) disappear and takes out the formatting for another image below so it looks like there is a huge chunk out of the footer missing.

If I take out the hyperlink for just that image, it reappears and the formatting is fine again.

Any ideas?

```html
 

/* Basic */

 body {
  background: #fff;
 }

  body.is-loading *, body.is-loading *:before, body.is-loading *:after {
   -moz-animation: none !important;
   -webkit-animation: none !important;
   -o-animation: none !important;
   -ms-animation: none !important;
   animation: none !important;
   -moz-transition: none !important;
   -webkit-transition: none !important;
   -o-transition: none !important;
   -ms-transition: none !important;
   transition: none !important;
  }

 body, input, select, textarea {
  color: #666;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5em;
 }

 a {
  color: #f32853;
  text-decoration: underline;
 }

  a:hover {
   text-decoration: none;
  }

 strong, b {
  color: #484848;
  font-weight: 700;
 }

 em, i {
  font-style: italic;
 }

 p {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
 }

 h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #484848;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
 }

  h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a, h6 a {
   color: inherit;
   text-decoration: none;
  }

 h2 {
  font-size: 1.75em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
 }

 h3 {
  font-size: 1.35em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
 }

 h4 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
 }

 h5 {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
 }

 h6 {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
 }

 sub {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em;
 }

 sup {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.5em;
 }

 hr {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
  margin: 2em 0;
 }

  hr.major {
   margin: 3em 0;
  }

 blockquote {
  border-left: solid 4px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
  font-style: italic;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 2em;
 }

 code {
  background: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.075);
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin: 0 0.25em;
  padding: 0.25em 0.65em;
 }

 pre {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  font-family: "Courier New", monospace;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
 }

  pre code {
   display: block;
   line-height: 1.75em;
   padding: 1em 1.5em;
   overflow-x: auto;
  }

 .align-left {
  text-align: left;
 }

 .align-center {
  text-align: center;
 }

 .align-right {
  text-align: right;
 }

   
  
/* List */

 ol {
  list-style: decimal;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  padding-left: 1.25em;
 }

  ol li {
   padding-left: 0.25em;
  }

 ul {
  list-style: disc;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
 }

  ul li {
   padding-left: 0.5em;
  }

  ul.alt {
   list-style: none;
   padding-left: 0;
  }

   ul.alt li {
    border-top: solid 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
    padding: 0.5em 0;
   }

    ul.alt li:first-child {
     border-top: 0;
     padding-top: 0;
    }

  ul.icons {
   cursor: default;
   list-style: none;
   padding-left: 0;
  }

   ul.icons li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
   }

    ul.icons li:last-child {
     padding-right: 0;
    }

    ul.icons li .icon:before {
     font-size: 2em;
    }

  ul.actions {
   cursor: default;
   list-style: none;
   padding-left: 0;
  }

   ul.actions li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1em 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
   }

    ul.actions li:last-child {
     padding-right: 0;
    }

   ul.actions.small li {
    padding: 0 0.5em 0 0;
   }

   ul.actions.vertical li {
    display: block;
    padding: 1em 0 0 0;
   }

    ul.actions.vertical li:first-child {
     padding-top: 0;
    }

    ul.actions.vertical li > * {
     margin-bottom: 0;
    }

   ul.actions.vertical.small li {
    padding: 0.5em 0 0 0;
   }

    ul.actions.vertical.small li:first-child {
     padding-top: 0;
    }

   ul.actions.fit {
    display: table;
    margin-left: -1em;
    padding: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: calc(100% + 1em);
   }

    ul.actions.fit li {
     display: table-cell;
     padding: 0 0 0 1em;
    }

     ul.actions.fit li > * {
      margin-bottom: 0;
     }

    ul.actions.fit.small {
     margin-left: -0.5em;
     width: calc(100% + 0.5em);
    }

     ul.actions.fit.small li {
      padding: 0 0 0 0.5em;
     }

 dl {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
 }

/* Table */

 .table-wrapper {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-x: auto;
 }

 table {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  width: 100%;
 }

  table tbody tr {
   border: solid 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
   border-left: 0;
   border-right: 0;
  }

   table tbody tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
    background-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.075);
   }

  table td {
   padding: 0.75em 0.75em;
  }

  table th {
   color: #484848;
   font-size: 0.9em;
   font-weight: 700;
   padding: 0 0.75em 0.75em 0.75em;
   text-align: left;
  }

  table thead {
   border-bottom: solid 2px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
  }

  table tfoot {
   border-top: solid 2px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
  }

  table.alt {
   border-collapse: separate;
  }

   table.alt tbody tr td {
    border: solid 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
    border-left-width: 0;
    border-top-width: 0;
   }

    table.alt tbody tr td:first-child {
     border-left-width: 1px;
    }

   table.alt tbody tr:first-child td {
    border-top-width: 1px;
   }

   table.alt thead {
    border-bottom: 0;
   }

   table.alt tfoot {
    border-top: 0;
   }

   
/* Header */

 #skel-layers-wrapper {
  padding-top: 6em;
 }

 body.landing #skel-layers-wrapper {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
 }

 #header {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0px 0.0375em 0.125em 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  color: #484848;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  height: 4.5em;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 4.4em;
  position: fixed;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
 }

  #header h1 {
   color: #484848;
   font-weight: 400;
   height: inherit;
   left: 1.25em;
   line-height: inherit;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
  }

  #header nav {
   height: inherit;
   line-height: inherit;
   position: absolute;
   right: 1.25em;
   top: 0;
   vertical-align: middle;
  }

   #header nav > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
   }

    #header nav > ul > li {
     border-radius: 4px;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: 2.5em;
     padding-left: 0;
    }

     #header nav > ul > li a {
      -moz-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -o-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
      transition: color 0.2s ease-in-out;
      color: #666;
      display: inline-block;
      text-decoration: none;
     }

      #header nav > ul > li a:hover {
       color: #484848;
      }

     #header nav > ul > li:first-child {
      margin-left: 0;
     }

     #header nav > ul > li .button {
      border-color: rgba(144, 144, 144, 0.25);
      box-shadow: none;
      height: 3em;
      line-height: 2.9em;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding: 0 1.5em;
      position: relative;
      top: -0.075em;
      vertical-align: middle;
     }

  #header .container {
   position: relative;
  }

   #header .container h1 {
    left: 0;
   }

   #header .container nav {
    right: 0;
   }

  #header.alt {
   background-color: transparent;
   border: 0;
   box-shadow: none;
   height: 3.25em;
   line-height: 3.25em;
   position: absolute;
  }

   #header.alt h1 {
    color: #ffffff;
    left: 2.5em;
    top: 2em;
   }

    #header.alt h1 a {
     color: #ffffff;
    }

   #header.alt nav {
    right: 2em;
    top: 2em;
   }

    #header.alt nav a {
     color: #ddd;
    }

     #header.alt nav a:active, #header.alt nav a:hover {
      color: #ffffff;
     }

   #header.alt .button {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color: #ffffff !important;
   }

   
   } </style>
</p>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td height="10" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
    &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="center" style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:900px; height:1916px;">
    &nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:900px; height:1728px;">
 <div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:900px; height:1728px;">
  <div>
   <a href="http://www.cvent.com/d/6fq1s1/4W" style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced9_01.png); position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:900px; height:369px;" title=""> </a></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/white-box1.png); position:absolute; left:0px; top:369px; width:900px; height:52px; background-color:#ffffff" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced9_03.png); position:absolute; left:0px; top:421px; width:217px; height:165px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="position:absolute; left:217px; top:421px; width:466px; height:118px; text-align:center; vertical-align:top;">
   <font color="#000000" size="5">YOU ARE INVITED</font><br />
   <br />
   <font size="4">Develop your &ldquo;Internet of Things&rdquo; application using<br />
   ThingSpace platform &ndash; a portal that provides developers<br />
   with robust tools and resources.</font></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced9_05.png); position:absolute; left:683px; top:421px; width:217px; height:165px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced9_06.png); position:absolute; left:217px; top:539px; width:466px; height:47px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Grey-Background.png); position:absolute; left:0px; top:586px; width:900px; height:34px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Grey-Background-08.png); position:absolute; left:0px; top:620px; width:449px; height:12px; background-color:#e6e7e8" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Red-Line.png); position:absolute; left:449px; top:620px; width:2px; height:146px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Grey-Background-10.png); position:absolute; left:451px; top:620px; width:449px; height:12px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Grey-Background-11.png); position:absolute; left:0px; top:632px; width:183px; height:168px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="position:absolute; left:183px; top:632px; width:181px; height:95px; text-align:center; vertical-align:top; background-color:#e6e7e8">
   <font color="#000000" size="6"><strong>WHEN</strong></font><br />
   <br />
   <font size="3">Tuesday, April 5, 2016<br />
   9:45am - 5:30pm</font><br />
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Grey-Background-12.png); position:absolute; left:364px; top:632px; width:85px; height:168px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Grey-Background-13.png); position:absolute; left:451px; top:632px; width:68px; height:168px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="position:absolute; left:519px; top:632px; width:216px; height:117px; text-align:center; vertical-align:top; background-color:#e6e7e8">
   <font color="#000000" size="6"><strong>WHERE</strong></font><br />
   <br />
   <font size="3">Verizon Innovation Center<br />
   201 Spear Street<br />
   San Francisco, CA 94105</font><br />
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Grey-Background-14.png); position:absolute; left:735px; top:632px; width:165px; height:168px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Grey-Background-15.png); position:absolute; left:183px; top:727px; width:181px; height:73px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Grey-Background-16.png); position:absolute; left:519px; top:749px; width:216px; height:51px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Grey-Background-17.png); position:absolute; left:449px; top:766px; width:2px; height:34px; background-color:#e6e7e8" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced9_20.png); position:absolute; left:0px; top:800px; width:900px; height:44px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced9_21.png); position:absolute; left:0px; top:844px; width:168px; height:884px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="position:absolute; left:168px; top:844px; width:564px; height:353px; text-align:center; vertical-align:top;">
   <font color="#000000" size="5"><strong>MOVE YOUR IoT INNOVATION<br />
   INTO THE REAL WORLD</strong></font><br />
   <br />
   <br />
   <font size="4"><font size="4">ThingSpace simplifies IoT application development and enables you<br />
   to go from prototype to solution faster than ever.<br />
   <br />
   ThingSpace provides the following tools and resources to help you create the next big IoT app.</font></font><br />
   <br />
   <p style="text-align: left;">
    <font size="4">&middot; </font><font size="2">A centralized IoT developer focused portal</font><br />
    <font size="4">&middot; </font><font size="2">RESTful Application Programming Interfaces (APIs)</font><br />
    <font size="4">&middot; </font><font size="2">Try It! feature - an API simulator</font><br />
    <font size="4">&middot; </font><font size="2">Application Enablement Platform (AEP)</font><br />
    <font size="4">&middot; </font><font size="2">A broad selection of Dev Kits</font><br />
    <font size="4">&middot; </font><font size="2">Documentation and resources</font></p>
  </div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced9_23.png); position:absolute; left:732px; top:844px; width:168px; height:884px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced9_24.png); position:absolute; left:168px; top:1197px; width:564px; height:39px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced9_25.png); position:absolute; left:168px; top:1236px; width:131px; height:492px;" title="">
   &nbsp;</div>
   
  <a href="http://www.cvent.com/d/6fq1s1/4W" target="_blank" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced10_26.png); position:absolute; left:299px; top:1236px; width:302px; height:72px;" title="">
  </div></a>
 <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced10_27.png); position:absolute; left:601px; top:1236px; width:131px; height:492px;" title="">
 </div>
 
 <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced10_28.png); position:absolute; left:299px; top:1308px; width:302px; height:38px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced10_29.png); position:absolute; left:299px; top:1346px; width:48px; height:382px;" title="">
 </div>
 <a href="https://thingspace.verizon.com/" target="_blank" style="cursor:hand">
  <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/ThingSpace-Button.png); position:absolute; left:347px; top:1346px; width:206px; height:170px;" title="">
  </div></a>
 <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced10_31.png); position:absolute; left:553px; top:1346px; width:48px; height:382px;" title="">
 </div>
 <div style="background-image:url(http://www.verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced10_32.png); position:absolute; left:347px; top:1516px; width:206px; height:212px;" title="">
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry! I had a character limit for this post and forgot to add it back in. Here is where the page is hosted - [link](http://verizonevent.com/tstest)

Answer (score 1):

Very hard to see without a link to the page.
Does your anchor tag have a position:relative; on it? This could cause problem with the absolute positioning of the img

Comment: This was it! I can't believe I messed up on this very basic thing. Thank you for the response. I tried to give you +1, but I am not high enough in reputation.

Comment: Haha me neither Samantha - and I always get down voted on here when Im just trying my best :-) Glad to be of help.

Comment: @SamanthaStultz don't forget to mark Mike's answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Created a fiddle out of your (limited) post. 
and it looks like you are calling images that are not uploaded to the server (error 404). These images in particular:

```
http://verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced10_32.png
http://verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced10_31.png
http://verizonevent.com/tstest/images/images/Email_Invite_900_sliced10_29.png
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wxgt8oz9/